# Solidity Interfaces & Calling other Contract Functions

Tags: solidity

I have a general question about Solidity. Right now I'm looking at a bunch of different contract examples to try and learn the basics, and one thing I'm totally not understanding is why a Contract A is allowed to call into a Contract B using an Interface X if Contract B doesn't implement that Interface X. I'll give an example:

Here is a Contract B:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract B {
    uint public totalSupply;
    
    function incrementTotalSupply() public {
        totalSupply++;
    }
    
    function getTotalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
        return totalSupply;
    }
}
```

And here is a Contract A that uses an interface X to call functions in Contract B:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

interface X {
    function getTotalSupply() external view returns (uint);
}

contract A {
    X state;
    
    function initializeState(address _address) public {
        state = X(_address);
    }
    
    function getTotalSupplyFromB() public view returns (uint) {
        return state.getTotalSupply();
    }
}
```

This may seem like a dumb question, but isn't it super weird that Contract A can call into Contract B even if B doesn't explicitly say `contract B is X` or something like that? Does anyone mind expanding on this? Thanks.

A secondary question I have is, well, what is the point of interfaces then? What are they generally used for?

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are designed to be easy to extend and use！

Wouldn't it be convenient to have an interface if you wanted to use other deployed contracts?

You just need to care about what methods it has, not how to implement it internally, let alone import its source code, okay！

Interfaces are very important in object-oriented programming languages. I think you should know that. You should learn more as a novice!

Answer (score 0):

The contract was originally designed to be called through the EOA address or any contract address. It gives Ethereum infinite composability. Contracts can become the basis for other contracts, such as AAVE, Uniswap.

For question 2, you can check the official doc [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.25/abi-spec.html).

> The Contract Application Binary Interface (ABI) is the standard way to interact with contracts in the Ethereum ecosystem, both from outside the blockchain and for contract-to-contract interaction. Data is encoded according to its type, as described in this specification. The encoding is not self describing and thus requires a schema in order to decode.